# what is a simple way to find the outliers of an array

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say I have the following array of integers, I wonder if there is a simple way to identify the outlier, which is 58 here.

[15, 17, 19, 16, 14, 58]

Comment: What's your definition of outlier? If you're doing statistics, one possible way is to remove, say, the top and bottom 10% of values. Another is to determine the median, and remove everything larger or smaller than the median times some factor. You have to describe your intentions more clearly to allow people to give helpful answers.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, elementary-number-theory don't seem like a good category for this question. You might want to re-tag.

Comment: Sorry, what should be a good category for this?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question about the definition of the outlier, but let me give it a try anyways - the number(s) that  is not in the range of majority of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard way of checking for outliers is to use quartiles and the interquartal range for defining thresholds. Take the median to divide your data in two halves, then use the medians of the upper and lower halves to divide your data into four parts. The resulting 3 numbers are your quartiles. In your case you get
$$Q_1=15\quad Q_2=16.5\quad Q_3=19$$
The interquartal range is $IQR = Q_3-Q_1=4$.
Common thresholds to detect outliers would be
$$T_{lo}=Q_1-1.5\cdot IQR=9\text{ and } T_{hi}=Q_3+1.5\cdot IQR=25$$
Any values less than $T_{lo}$ or greater than $T_{hi}$ are classified as outliers. So the value 58 would clearly be detected as an outlier.

Comment: awesome! what if this is a 3 numbers array? for example, [16, 17, 58] or 4 numbers array [16, 17, 19, 58]?

Comment: With so few data it's hard to talk about outliers. Anyway, as you've already noticed, the standard method I've explained can obviously not be used. In these cases I'd simply take the median $m$ and define $T_{lo}=m/c$ and $T_{hi}=m\cdot c$ with some heuristically chosen $c>1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Depending on how your data is distributed, points more than three standard deviations away from the arithmetic mean may also be considered outliers.

Comment: @FixedPoint sorry what does it mean "three standard deviations away"?

Comment: @tom You have your data set [15, 17, 19, 16, 14, 58]. You find its mean 23.1667. You find its standard deviation 17.151 meaning three standard deviations are 3*17.151=51.45. Then find the numbers that are more than three standard deviations away from the mean so any number less than -28 or more than 74 can be an outlier. In this case it doesn't pick out 58 though.

Comment: @FixedPoint why specifically three std-dev away? Why not 1.5 ?